# How can I compute mining profitability?

Tags: mining-profitability

It was asked elsewhere, but I'm re-asking the question in a less time sensitive way. Can you please list some of the techniques, charts, spreadsheets, calculators or other tools that help someone to compute mining profitability?

Answer (score 11):

There are several [mining profitability calculators](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Profitability_Calculator) available.  In order to obtain useful data from these, you'll need to predict how the price of bitcoins and the mining difficulty factor will change.  Price charts are available at [bitcoincharts.com](http://bitcoincharts.com/), and difficulty charts are available at [bitcoin.sipa.be](http://bitcoin.sipa.be/).  There are also charts of the price to difficulty ratio available at [bitcoinx.com](http://bitcoinx.com/charts/).

Answer (score 2):

I`ve made a simple calculator that can calculate estimated mining profitability (given that you know how much power you are using and how much it costs you).
http://tpbitcalc.appspot.com/
But the problem with all mining calculators is that the Bitcoin economy can shift very often. Difficulty and bitcoin exchange ratio change quite often, and the latter sometimes very rapidly, so projecting too far into the future has to be taken with a grain of salt.